# How to remove a character " * " from a column of cells in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

[**The " * " in between the numbers need to go**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QLUfb.png)

I have already prepared the loop for iterating over the column cells

function myErase(data) {
  for (var i=0; i

please help me out

Ive Changed the code a bit, i now got this code which takes away the " * " from the numbers but doesnt do it across an entire column of cell which contain the same character.

```
 function myErase() { var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("ID"); var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Sheet"); var cellvalue = sheet.getRange(5,4,10,2).getValue(); var tempstring = cellvalue.toString().replace("*",""); sheet.getRange(5,6,10).setValue(tempstring); }
```

Comment: First time using the platform, im a new coder and need help with this seemingly easy task.

Comment: You can use Javascript 1.6 methods such as `String#replace`. You use Apps Script specifics like `SpreadsheetApp` (Use **`Help -> API Reference`** in Script Editor menu to open documentation) to interface with spreadsheets and other Google products.